# Storing history of data changes in notification table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, hash, notifications

I'm building a notifications system. In my app user receives notifications about the event or user he follows. In my notification table i store the information about changes of state of a given object i.e event time changed, event postponed, canceled etc.

But i don't want to refer to these information through object lookup directly because then i would not have a history, just a current state.

So the solution is so that after every change of state, new notification is created with changed values coppied to some data field in this table.
But i'm not sure what is the right way to store this data.
Maybe i could store it as a JSON or a hash?

Answer (score 0):

you can store current state in your notifications table and keep an auditLog table for the changes on each notification object.

off topic, for notifications: using rails polymorphic associations would ease your life.